# Dynamic JSON file vs API

Tags: json, architecture, asp.net-web-api

I am designing a system with 30,000 objects or so and can't decide between the two: either have a JSON file pre computed for each one and get data by pointing to URL of the file (I think Twitter does something similar) or have a PHP/Perl/whatever else script that will produce JSON object on the fly when requested, from let's say database, and send it back. Is one more suited for than another? I guess if it takes a long time to generate the JSON data it is better to have already done JSON files. What if generating is as quick as accessing a database? Although I suppose one has a dedicated table in the database specifically for that. Data doesn't change very often so updating is not a constant thing. In that respect the data is static for all intense and purposes.

Anyways, any thought would be much appreciated!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try MongoDB which retrieves the objects as JSON and is highly scalable and easy to setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I didn't know there is a DB that outputs JSON straight out. However, I am still not sure whether dynamic files are better than API driven or visa versa.